# how to fix Cannot read property 'length' of undefined on angular datatable

Tags: angular

Guys, I want to update my database using BehaviorSubject and Promises and for that, I build a program but I found that my variable (that contains the object of Datatable data) undefined after debugging for that I found:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at Object.eval
>   [as updateDirectives]

My code:

component.html:

```
<div id="products" class="page-layout carded fullwidth inner-scroll">

    <div class="top-bg accent"></div>

    <div class="center">
        <div class="header accent"
             fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
             fxLayout.gt-sm="row" fxLayoutAlign.gt-sm="space-between center">

            <div class="logo mb-24 mb-md-0"
                 fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                <mat-icon class="logo-icon s-32 mr-16" [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{delay:'50ms',scale:'0.2'}}">
                    shopping_basket
                </mat-icon>
                <span class="logo-text h1" [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{delay:'100ms',x:'-25px'}}">
                    Products
                </span>
            </div>

            <div class="search-wrapper mx-32 mx-md-0">
                <div class="search" fxFlex fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
                    <mat-icon>search</mat-icon>
                    <input #filter placeholder="Search for a product">
                </div>
            </div>

            <button mat-raised-button
                    [routerLink]="'/apps/e-commerce/products/new'"
                    class="add-product-button fuse-white mt-24 mt-md-0">
                <span>ADD NEW PRODUCT</span>
            </button>


        </div>

        <div class="content-card">

            <mat-table class="products-table"
                       #table [dataSource]="dataSource"
                       matSort
                       [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}"
                       fusePerfectScrollbar>

                <ng-container matColumnDef="Nfamille">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>ID</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">
                        <p class="text-truncate">{{product.FirstName}}</p>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Prenom">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product">
                        <p class="text-truncate">{{product.LastName}}</p>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Etat">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef fxHide mat-sort-header fxShow.gt-md>Category</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product" fxHide fxShow.gt-md>
                        <p class="category text-truncate">
                            {{product.DriverStatus}}
                        </p>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>
                <ng-container matColumnDef="Departemant">
                    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header fxHide fxShow.gt-xs>Price</mat-header-cell>
                    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let product" fxHide fxShow.gt-xs>
                        <p class="price text-truncate">
                            {{product.DepartmentString}}
                        </p>
                    </mat-cell>
                </ng-container>

                <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky:true"></mat-header-row>

                <mat-row *matRowDef="let product; columns: displayedColumns;"
                         class="product"
                         matRipple>
                </mat-row>

            </mat-table>

            <mat-paginator #paginator
                           [length]="dataSource.filteredData.length"
                           [pageIndex]="0"
                           [pageSize]="10"
                           [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 25, 100]">
            </mat-paginator>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and My component.ts:

```
 dataSource: FilesDataSource | null;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['Nfamille','Prenom','Etat','Departemant'];

  listdata: MatTableDataSource<any>;  

  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, {static: true})
  paginator: MatPaginator;

  @ViewChild(MatSort, {static: true})
  sort: MatSort;

  @ViewChild('filter', {static: true})
  filter: ElementRef;

  constructor(private service: GetionChauffeursService) { this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();}
    private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dataSource = new FilesDataSource(this.service, this.paginator, this.sort);

    fromEvent(this.filter.nativeElement, 'keyup')
    .pipe(
        takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll),
        debounceTime(150),
        distinctUntilChanged()
    )
    .subscribe(() => {
        if ( !this.dataSource )
        {
            return;
        }

        this.dataSource.filter = this.filter.nativeElement.value;
    });
}





}
export class FilesDataSource extends DataSource<any>
{
    private _filterChange = new BehaviorSubject('');
    private _filteredDataChange = new BehaviorSubject('');


    constructor(
      private service: GetionChauffeursService,
        private _matPaginator: MatPaginator,
        private _matSort: MatSort
    )
    {
        super();

        this.filteredData = this.service.listDriverElementEntity;
        console.log('here filter ' + this.service.listDriverElementEntity);//That log is show me undefiend

    }

    connect(): Observable<any[]>
    {
        const displayDataChanges = [
            this.service.onProductsChanged,
            this._matPaginator.page,
            this._filterChange,
            this._matSort.sortChange
        ];

        return merge(...displayDataChanges)
            .pipe(
                map(() => {
                        let data = this.service.listDriverElementEntity.slice();

                        data = this.filterData(data);

                        this.filteredData = [...data];

                        data = this.sortData(data);
                            const startIndex = this._matPaginator.pageIndex * this._matPaginator.pageSize;
                        return data.splice(startIndex, this._matPaginator.pageSize);
                    }
                ));
    }

    get filteredData(): any
    {
        return this._filteredDataChange.value;
    }

    set filteredData(value: any)
    {
        this._filteredDataChange.next(value);
    }

    get filter(): string
    {
        return this._filterChange.value;
    }

    set filter(filter: string)
    {
        this._filterChange.next(filter);
    }


    filterData(data): any
    {
        if ( !this.filter )
        {
            return data;
        }
        return FuseUtils.filterArrayByString(data, this.filter);
    }
}
```

and finally, this is my service:

```
 driverList: any;
  resultDrivers:GetUIDriverManagementParamResult;
  listDriverElementEntity:ListDriverElementEntity[];
  onProductsChanged: BehaviorSubject<any>;
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {        
    // Set the defaults
    this.onProductsChanged = new BehaviorSubject({}); }
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      Promise.all([
          this.getProducts()
      ]).then(
          () => {
              resolve();
          },
          reject
      );
  });
  }
 getProducts(): Promise<any>
    {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          this.http.post(`${this.GeneralURL}/GetUIDriverManagementParam`, JSON.stringify(this.data), this.httpOptions)
                .subscribe((response: any) => {
                  this.driverList = json2array(response) ;
                  this.resultDrivers =  this.driverList ;
                 this.listDriverElementEntity = this.resultDrivers[0].ListDriverElement;
                 console.log( this.listDriverElementEntity);
                    //this.products = response;
                    this.onProductsChanged.next(this.listDriverElementEntity);
                    resolve(response);
                }, reject);
        });
    }
```

Comment: I ran into this just the other day with mat-paginator. Fixed it for now with safe nav operator e.g. dataSource?.filteredData.length ... There is an "angular" way to fix this so the component wont load until the data arrives, using "resolvers", which work like gaurds. I can't leave an answer because I'm learning that myself at the moment.

Comment: nope I tried it before but it still give me the some error

Comment: Bummer. Templates are tough to debug. If it's one-of you can use `{{ myval | json }}` in a visible part of the template. But since this is probably loading multiple times before it gets data you might `{{ log(myval) }}` somewhere in the template, then in the controller `log (x) { console.log(x) }`. My guess is you'll see it load several times as undefined before it finally gets a value.

Comment: Yeah, it loaded many time before it gets data (so I need a call back function?) if yes how can I do that?

Comment: Use a resolver on your route to fetch the data: https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve Then change your component to read data from the ActivatedRoute. https://codeburst.io/the-right-way-to-prefetch-data-for-your-angular-components-pages-1e5cce099cee This way your component won't load until the data is ready.

Answer (score 0):

What I think happening is that you are trying to access the data before it has arrived from the service. You can simply use *ngIf condition where you want to display data which displays only if there is some data.

Comment: how can I d it 'at my knowledge, I don't think a simple *ngIf can solve my problem cause it will give me just a null' so how?